# Factory pattern using class_exists on CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, factory-pattern

I have the following code (trying to simulate a factory pattern):

**CoinConnectorFactory.php**

```
public static function build($connector) {
    $connector = "CoinConnector" . ucwords($connector);
    if (class_exists($connector)) {
        return new $connector();
    } else {
        throw new InvalidConnectorType($connector);
    }
}
```

And the following folder structure:

```
/app
    /Plugin
        /CoinConnector
             /Lib
                 CoinConnectorFactory.php
                 CoinConnectorGogulski.php
```

So the problem is, I pass to the `build` method as a `$connector` variable this value `gogulski` but when get into `class_exists` like this:

```
class_exists('CoinConnectorGogulski')
```

Never find the class (that have the same name that the file) and always throw the exception.

Only if I add this line before check if the class exist CakePHP is able to find the class

```
include_once APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'CoinConnector' . DS . 'Lib' . DS . $connector . '.php';
```

Comment: You do realize you have to `include`/`require` dependency files in order to use them, right? An autoload function will not work with a `class_exists` check, fyi.

Comment: Is CoinConnectorFactory in another namespace than CoinConnectorGogulski. From your structure it looks like that way. If CoinConnectorGogulski is in the root namespace you have to check for \CoinConnectorGogulski. With backslash. The same with the instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how I fix my problem at the end:

```
public static function build($connector) {
    $connector = "CoinConnector" . ucwords($connector);
    App::uses($connector, 'CoinConnector.Lib');
    if (class_exists($connector)) {
        return new $connector();
    } else {
        throw new InvalidConnectorType($connector);
    }
}
```